# How to achieve controls like InDesign in a Word document

Tags: adobe-indesign, microsoft-word

I want to create a template for a Microsoft Word document. I want the control of InDesign in terms of layout and Master Pages. How can I have both?

I have read online that I cannot save Indesign files as a word document. Is there any way that I can create a template in InDesign and export to Word? If not, is there any way I could create a Word file with the level of customization options like InDesign?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, no, no and.. no :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Word is **not intended nor designed** to allow the level of layout control more high end design software allows.

What you are asking is not possible.

This is kind of like saying you "want the level of speed and handling of a Ferrari for your [1985 Yugo GV](http://time.com/4723114/50-worst-cars-of-all-time/)". It is just not going to happen.

In addition, because InDesign employs many more features than Word, there is no direct path to take an InDesign file to Word.

In general terms, Word is a **text editor**. It is designed to write text. That's it, not create layouts and artwork. Sure the lines blur slightly with the ability to import images and draw a few rudimentary shapes in Word. However, Word will *never* support free object control of elements (ability to click and drag them anywhere you want) the way InDesign does.

Conversely, InDesign *does* support free object-level control over elements. There are major issues trying to take that free control and translate it to a rigid structured environment such as Word. While you can get *text* from InDesign to Word rather easily, retaining layout and form is basically hit or miss - often resulting in more misses than hits.

If you are looking for something more "middle of the road" you may want to look into some less expensive software which is *intended* to offer some layout control. Things like Apple's Pages, or Scribis are *much* less expensive than InDesign but still offer **far** more visual control than Word ever will. (I *hate* to write this.. but even Microsoft Publisher would be better than Word if you are seeking layout control).